# Concat String using Groovy Script

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy. I have a csv file which has only 1 field.
I need to concat the fields with a comma (,).
Its a very simple requirement, but what I am not sure is do we need to create a Array list or there is a simpler way to achieve this?

Input:

```
ABC
XYZ
123
```

Output: `ABC,XYZ,123`

```
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;
def Message processData(Message message) {
    //Body 

    def body = message.getBody();
    def userlist = new ArrayList<body>()
    userlist.join(",");
    return(userlist);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use [CharSequence.readLines()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#readLines()) to split multi-line string to an array of single-line strings and then join them

```
def data = '''\
ABC
XYZ
123'''

def output = data.readLines().join(',')
assert output == 'ABC,XYZ,123'
```

Comment: Hello, I get the following error 
java.lang.Exception: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object ABC,XYZ with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message'@ line 26 in script1.groovy

Comment: It's not anymore about groovy. That's about your knowledge of SAP integrator api... I think `message.setBody(output)` then `return message` should solve an issue.

Comment: Thank you. However this still dosent resolve my issue. 
No signature of method: java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.readLines() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: def Message processData(Message message) {
    //Body 
       def body = message.getBody();
       output = body.readLines().join(',')
       message.setBody(output);
       return message;

Comment: if message.getBody() returns [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) then `def body = message.getBody().toString("UTF-8")` should help to get body as string (you have to check if charset=UTF-8 for your file body).

Comment: Thank you so much, this has helped.
I am getting the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `replaceAll()` method

```
def data = '''\
ABC
XYZ
123'''

def output = data.replaceAll( /\n/, ',' )
assert output == 'ABC,XYZ,123'
```

Comment: Hello, I get the following error 
java.lang.Exception: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object ABC,XYZ with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message'@ line 26 in script1.groovy

Comment: I assume you need to call a constructor, like `new Message( output )`

Comment: Hello, Does this not return the output ?
`    import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    def Message processData(Message message) {
    //Body 
    def body = message.getBody();
    message.setBody(body + "Body is modified");
    def output = body.replaceAll( /\n/, ',' )
    return output;`

Comment: this returns a String, whereas your method signature expects a `Message`

Comment: this `def Message processData(Message message)` must be changed to `String processData(Message message){`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help.
Modified the code as below.
Both of the below codes work now by adding toString and the encoding.
1)

```
        def Message processData(Message message) {
    //Body 
       def body = message.getBody().toString("UTF-8");
       output = body.readLines().join(',')
       message.setBody(output);
       return message;
```

2. 

```
 def Message processData(Message message) {
//Body 
   def body = message.getBody().toString("UTF-8");
   output = body.replaceAll( /\n/, ',' )
   message.setBody(output);
   return message;
```